# How do I fix this error on unity: Cannot implicitly convert type float to UnityEngine.transform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to do something, and I get this error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type float to UnityEngine.transform
```

code:

```
private Transform EndPos;
EndPos = transform.position.x + 40f;
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, EndPos, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: endpos = transform.position.x (a float) + another float.. and you are trying to store it in a transform, you would need to set the endpos to the position, and change only the x value

Answer (score 1):

`EndPos` is type `Transform`. You are trying to set it to `transform.position.x` which is type `float`.

I **think** what you are trying to do is:

```
EndPos.position = transform.position + (Vector3.right * 40f);
```

This sets `EndPos` 40 units to the right of `transform`'s current position.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing "EndPos = transform.position.x + 40f;"
Change the "X" of EndPos (EndPos.position.x) and then use it.